# Custom comment type wordpress

Tags: wordpress

When i insert a comment i use the following code

```
$data = array(
    'comment_post_ID' => $postid,
    'comment_content' => 'User Review',
    'comment_type' => 'review',
    'user_id' => $userid,
    'comment_date' => $time,
    'comment_approved' => 1,
);

$commentid  = wp_insert_comment($data);
```

If i try to get these comments based on "comment_type", I am not getting results

```
    $args = array(

    'user_id' => $userid,
    'post_type' => 'review'     
);
$comments = get_comments($args);
```

get_comments can't be used for getting comments of particular type?

How to get comments of type review?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code, 
I hope this will help.

```
$args = array(

    'user_id' => $userid,
    'type' => 'review'     
);
$comments = get_comments($args);
```

Comment: Docs is very clear bro...
`post_type` is specialy for post/page/CPT or etc...
and `type` is for `comment_type`...

Answer (score 4):

You can write a custom query to get comments of type review.

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$query = "SELECT * 
        FROM $wpdb->comments 
        WHERE $wpdb->comments.user_id =$userid AND $wpdb->comments.comment_type = 'review'";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($query);
print_r($results);
?>
```

Later, you can just loop through the results to print them. And if you want comments on particular post then add a condition in WHERE clause, AND comment_post_ID = $post_id.