# Wordpress Create Custom Comment Type

Tags: wordpress, comments

I have a page when I want multiple comment_template, so I want each of my comment_template to have different type so I see different comments in those 2.

My get_comments look like this

```
  $args = array(
            'post_id' => get_the_ID(),
            'orderby' => 'comment_date',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'type' => 'tips'
  );
  $comments = get_comments($args);
```

The problem is when I post the comment, I didn't find how to assign this post type to the comment, so I am not able to show them up with get_comments()

I tried to add my comment form like this but that still dosen't work

```
$comment_args = array( 
        'type' => 'tips'
    );
    comment_form($comment_args);
```

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_type check this out you can specify comments type this way

Comment: Yeah ive seen this but that's only to display the comment type. What I want is that when someone write a comment, the comment_type would be tips

Comment: Hey, check this one it may help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21404466/custom-comment-type-wordpress

Comment: Yeah I saw it already but this example use wp_insert_comment($data); an d I want to use comment_form();

Comment: I tried to add <input type="hidden" name="comment_type" value="tips" id="comment_type" /> to my comment_form but still dosen't work. Ive tried only type instead of comment_type also

Answer (score 0):

There are several steps to saving a custom comment type which, by the way, is technically not supported in WordPress as is a custom post type.

A. WordPress has 3 types of comments: ping, trackback, and blank for regular comment.

B. Using this premise of WP allowing a blank field to associate for "normal comment", we can now insert our new CCT using any name we want.

C. You must use `comment_form_defaults` in a function to define an array outside the comments form and pass it as a parameter. (Otherwise you can alter the $arguments in `comment_form($args)` directly on callout.)

```
add_filter('comment_form_defaults', 'wpse33967503_defaults_comments_positive');    
function wpse33967503_defaults_comments_positive($default)
{    
    global $comment_id;
    $actnonce = 'action_tips'; 
    $action = empty( $_REQUEST['action_tips'] ) 
           ? false : $_REQUEST['action_tips'];
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $action != false ) 
    {  
        if( isset(  $_POST['custom_tips'] ) ){ 
        $ctype    = $_POST['custom_tips'];

    $default['fields']['comment_type'] = '<p class="comment-form-tips '. $ctype .'">
    <input type="hidden" name="action_tips" value="'. $actnonce .'" 
    id="action_tips" />
    <input type="hidden" name="comment_type" value="'. $ctype .'" 
    id="comment_type" /></p>';
        }
    }     
    return $default;       
}
```

D. Now we can inject this input into the comment form, but validation is always a good thing.

```
add_filter( 'preprocess_comment', 'wpse33967503_preprocess_comment_handler', 12, 1 );
function wpse33967503_preprocess_comment_handler( $commentdata ) 
{     
    if( ( isset( $_POST['comment_type'] ) ) && ( $_POST['comment_type'] != '') ) { 
    $commentdata['comment_type'] = wp_filter_nohtml_kses( $_POST['comment_type'] );
    }
        return $commentdata;    
}
```

Feel free to add messages or even a admin validation... I am just checking that it gets posted.

Your CCT is now part of the commentdata (not comment_meta). this is the regular comment data parameters that are inherit of WP.

Here are the default comment data sets in wp_comments table. Technically you could custom type just about any of these.

```
comment_ID: ID for the comment
comment_post_ID: The post for which the comment is posted
comment_author: Comment author name
comment_author_email: Author name for the comment
comment_author_url: Author url
comment_author_IP: Author IP address
comment_date: Comment Date
comment_date_gmt: GMT time of the comment
comment_content: Contents of the comment (comment body)
comment_karma: Is there default karma calculation? Maybe rating?
comment_approved: Flag for the comment status.
comment_agent: 
comment_type: functionality can be used like custom post type
comment_parent: For threaded comment
user_id: user id if comment author is a registered user of the site.
```